# Get the string after the aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I type:

```
blah.com/page.aspx/Touch?test=2
```

How could I get 'Touch' in Page_Load?

Thanks

Comment: parse the url string, that's what I do.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  Have you bothered looking at using a `Regex`? Or simply parsing the string?  Are you looking for just that word?  Can the word change?  Research man, research!!

Comment: are you using mvc routing?

Comment: No, but I still need /Touch because WebServices were not returning JSON.

Comment: is the url always starting with blah.com/page.aspx/ or will that vary also? otherwise you could simply split the string on '/' and get the last part. and strip the last part for everything before the '?'. If there is no '?' you still have the 1 part that contains "touch" in this case. just thinking out loud, best I can come up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the [PathInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx) property of the Request object.

from the linked page:

> For the URL `Http://www.contoso.com/virdir/page.html/tail`, the PathInfo value is /tail.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Request.Querystring`. Take a look at this msdn documentation page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Ops! Sorry, I misunderstood the question. This will require some parse on url or, if you'd like to make scripts like that you should try MVC.